# Numerical integration of lambda function with gsl

Tags: c++, lambda, gsl, numerical-integration

I am working with gsl to integrate a function. That function is built in a lambda function that has as input a double and a void *, and as output a double.
Now, everything works fine if I use the lambda without any variable capture. But if I do variable capturing, it doesn't work any more.

Could anyone explain me why so?

Here are two snippets of code that I made up to explain my problem:

This one works fine:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    double beg = 0;
    double end = 10;

    auto f = [] (double x, void * p) {return 2.0;};

    gsl_integration_workspace * w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (GSL_INTEGRATION_WORKSPACE_SIZE);

    double result;
    double error;

    gsl_function F;
    F.function = f;
    F.params = NULL;

    gsl_integration_qags (&F, beg, end, 0, GSL_INTEGRATION_RELATIVE_PRECISION, GSL_INTEGRATION_WORKSPACE_SIZE, w, &result, &error);

    cout<<result<<endl;

}
```

While this one

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    double beg = 0;
    double end = 10;

    double p = 2.0;

    auto f = [&] (double x, void * p) {return p;};

    gsl_integration_workspace * w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (GSL_INTEGRATION_WORKSPACE_SIZE);

    double result;
    double error;

    gsl_function F;
    F.function = f;
    F.params = NULL;

    gsl_integration_qags (&F, beg, end, 0, GSL_INTEGRATION_RELATIVE_PRECISION, GSL_INTEGRATION_WORKSPACE_SIZE, w, &result, &error);

    cout<<result<<endl;

}
```

Yields on the line

```
F.function = f;
```

the following error:

```
Assigning to 'double (*)(double, void *)' from incompatible type '<lambda at /[omissis]/main.cpp>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer given by @user657267 is correct. That is why a small wrapper is needed to convert lambas with capture to gsl_function.

[Here is the wrapper for the f gsl_function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413206/2472169) and [Here is the wrapper for the fdf gsl_function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24602657/2472169)

You can  convert lambda functions to gsl_function after using the wrapper proposed in these two answers in the following way (I haven't invented the version with std::function, it was a well known answer. The template version I haven't seen before my answer).

```
// std::function version
double a = 1;
gsl_function_pp Fp([=](double x)->double{return a*x;}); 
gsl_function *F = static_cast<gsl_function*>(&Fp); 

//template version
double a = 1;
auto ptr = [=](double x)->double{return a*x;};
gsl_function_pp<decltype(ptr)> Fp(ptr);
gsl_function *F = static_cast<gsl_function*>(&Fp);
```

Comment: If you liked, you could give a vote up to the other answers :)

Comment: where is the `std::function`?

Comment: The lambda function was converted to std::function

Answer (score 3):

Only lambdas without captures can be converted to function pointers.

[expr.prim.lambda]

> 6 The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression with **no
>   lambda-capture** has a public non-virtual non explicit const **conversion
>   function to pointer to function** with C++ language linkage (7.5) having
>   the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function
>   call operator.

Essentially what this means is that

```
[] (double, void*) {return 2.0;};
```

acts as though it were defined as

```
class Lambda
{
public:
  double operator()(double, void*);
  operator double(*)(double, void*)() const;
};
```

if the lambda has a capture however the conversion function is not defined, and the lambda cannot be converted to a regular function pointer.