# Pointer to member function of an object

Tags: c++, pointers, gsl

I would like to integrate a function with gsl. Therefor I have to define a function `f` (the integrant, which has to be of the form `double (*)(double, void*)`). For the call of the gsl integration method I need to define a struct, which contains a pointer to a function (this struct is called `gsl_function`).

```
gsl_function F;
F.function = &MyClass::my_f;
```

The function `f` must be implemented in a class (in the same class from which the integration procedure should be called). How can I assign the pointer above correctly, since the 2nd line is not compiling and leads to the error:

```
cannot convert ‘double (MyClass::*)(double, void*)’ to ‘double (*)(double, void*)’ in assignment.
```

Here the definition of `my_f`

```
 struct my_f_params { double a; double b;};

   double my_f (double x, void * p) {
   struct my_f_params * params = (struct my_f_params *)p;
   double a = (params->a);
   double b = (params->b);
   return 1.0/(sqrt(a * (1.0 + x)*(1.0 + x)*(1.0 + x) + (1-a) * std::pow((1.0 + x), (3.0 * (1.0 + b))))); 
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a `static` member function as callback there. I suppose the `void*` parameter can be (mis-)used to pass your `this` pointer as necessary.

Comment: Pointers to members are not normal pointers. You will have to wrap it inside a flat function. There are many examples of this technique on SO.

Comment: Think about the `void*` parameter of `gsl_function::function`. What could it be possibly used for?

Answer (score 1):

> which has to be of the form `double (*)(double, void*)`

Non static member function declarations involve the implicit call scope qualifier as stated in the error message

```
double (MyClass::*)(double, void*)
     // ^^^^^^^^^
```

This is different from the callback function pointer definition.

What you probably can do with such interface, is to pass the `this` pointer through the `void*` argument of the callback function:

```
class MyClass {
    static double func(double d,void* thisPtr) {
        MyClass* myClass = (MyClass*)thisPtr;
        // do something
    }
};
```

As mentioned [in the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Providing-the-function-to-solve.html) you can set the params like that in a wrapper class:

```
class gsl_function_wrapper {
public:    
    gsl_function_wrapper() {
         F.function = &func;
         F.params = this;
    }
private:
    gsl_function F;

    double a;
    double b;

    static double func(double d,void* thisPtr) {
        gsl_function_wrapper* myWrapper = (gsl_function_wrapper*)thisPtr;
        // do something with a and b
        foo(d,myWrapper->a,myWrapper->b);
    }
};
```

Comment: Please provide correct citation to where you got this solution (it was not on the GSL website). Possible correct source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413206/2472169