# gsl integration within a function c++

Tags: c++, gsl

I am just trying integrate over a function in C++. I have been trying to use gsl as I have seen this recommended online. I followed the gsl example with little success.

This is my C++ code:

```
double inverseE(double z){
   double inverseE = 1.0/(std::sqrt(Om0*std::pow(1.0+z,3.0)+1.0-Om0));
   return inverseE;
}

double comoving_distance(double z){
   gsl_integration_workspace * w
     = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000);

   double result, error;

   gsl_function iE;
   iE.function = &inverseE;

   gsl_integration_qags (&iE, 0, z, 0, 1e-7, 1000,
                           w, &result, &error);

   gsl_integration_workspace_free (w);

   cout << result << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

For clarification the same code in Python (which works) looks like this:

```
def iE(z):
     return 1/(np.sqrt(Om0*np.power(1+z,3)+1-Om0))

def comoving_distance(z):
     return (c/H0)*quad(iE,0,z)[0]
```

Where quad performs the integration (it's a scipy module).

I get two error messages:

*ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&cosmo::inverseE’ [-fpermissive]*

*cannot convert ‘double (cosmo::*)(double)’ to ‘double (*)(double, void*)’ in assignment*
cosmo is the name of the class which contains both of these functions.

It seems to be that this should not be a difficult thing to do. Advice as to where I am going wrong would be much appreciated!

**EDIT: class**

```
#include <iostream>    // using IO functions
#include <string>      // using string
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;



class cosmo {
private:
   double H0;
   double Om0;
   double Ob0;
   double c;
   double pi;
   double G;

public:
   // Constructor with default values for data members
   cosmo(double Hubble0 = 70, double OmegaM0 = 0.3,
           double OmegaB0 = 0.05) {
         H0 = Hubble0;
         Om0 = OmegaM0;
         Ob0 = OmegaB0;
         c = 3e8;
         pi = 3.141592653589793;
         G = 6.67408e-11;

}

double inverseE(double z){
   double inverseE = 1.0/(std::sqrt(Om0*std::pow(1.0+z,3.0)+1.0-Om0));
   return inverseE;
}

double comoving_distance(double z){
   gsl_integration_workspace * w
     = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000);

   double result, error;

   gsl_function iE;
   iE.function = &inverseE;

   gsl_integration_qags (&iE, 0, z, 0, 1e-7, 1000,
                           w, &result, &error);

   gsl_integration_workspace_free (w);

   cout << result << endl;

   return 0;
}


};
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? The nature of your error, for example, strongly suggests that this is in a class definition. If so, we need to see that.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the class now.

Comment: Afaik, you can't pass a pointer to a member function like this. Pointer to member-functions do not have a meaning without a pointer to the object you want to call the function on.

Comment: Okay if I remove the & then I only get the second error: **cannot convert ‘double (cosmo::)(double)’ to ‘double ()(double, void)’ in assignment* cosmo is the name of the class which contains both of these functions.** Is it possible to deal with this?

Comment: There is a simple workaround that allows you to integrate member functions  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413206/2472169

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems:

**1/** GSL expects your inverseE function to have the following prototype

```
double inverseE(double z,void *use_data);
```

in your code you have declared:

```
double inverseE(double z);
```

**2/** Like your code is in C++ and GSL is a C library, you have to make your C++ function callable from C.

The solution is to declare your `inverseE` function as follow:

```
extern "C" {
  double inverseE(double z,void *) {
      double inverseE = 1.0/(std::sqrt(Om0*std::pow(1.0+z,3.0)+1.0-Om0));
      return inverseE;
   }
}
```

This `extern "C"` makes your C++ function binary compatible with C call convention.

With these two modifications I think your code should be ok.

---

**UPDATE: 2/**

In my answer I considered in **2/** that `inverseE` was a *function*. Here I consider the case where it is a *method* of your class.

This is an example where `void *user_data` comes to the rescue:

Declare this wrapper:

```
  extern "C" {
  double YourClass_f_wrap(double z, void *user_data)
  {
    YourClass *this_ptr = (YourClass *)user_data;
    return this_ptr->f(z);
  }
  }
```

Then `YourClass` is defined as follow:

```
class YourClass
{
 public:
  struct IntegrationResult
  {
    double result, error;
    size_t n_intervals;
  };

 public:
  double f(double x) const; // defines f to integrate
  IntegrationResult integrate_f() const; // integrates f using GSL lib

  ...
};
```

As you mentioned in your comment some care must be taken concerning forward declaration. To be clear, please find below a complete runnning example that reproduce the result of [the GSL official doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Numerical-integration-examples.html#Numerical-integration-examples) but using a C++ class with a method `f()`

**Complete running code:**

Can be compiled with:

```
g++ gslIntegrationExample.cpp -lgsl -lcblas -o gslIntegrationExample
```

Code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>

namespace details
{
  extern "C" {
  double YourClass_f_wrap(double z, void *user_data);
  }
}

class YourClass
{
 public:
  struct IntegrationResult
  {
    double result, error;
    size_t n_intervals;
  };

 public:
  double f(double x) const
  {
    return std::log(alpha_ * x) / std::sqrt(x);
  }

  IntegrationResult integrate_f() const
  {
    gsl_integration_workspace *w =
        gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(1000);

    assert(w != nullptr);

    IntegrationResult toReturn;

    gsl_function F;
    F.function = &details::YourClass_f_wrap;
    F.params = (void *)this;

    gsl_integration_qags(&F, 0, 1, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &toReturn.result,
                         &toReturn.error);

    toReturn.n_intervals = w->size;

    gsl_integration_workspace_free(w);

    return toReturn;
  }

 protected:
  double alpha_ = 1;
};

namespace details
{
  extern "C" {
  double YourClass_f_wrap(double z, void *user_data)
  {
    YourClass *this_ptr = (YourClass *)user_data;
    return this_ptr->f(z);
  }
  }
}

int main()
{
  YourClass yourClass;

  auto integrationResult = yourClass.integrate_f();

  double expected = -4.0;
  std::printf("result          = % .18f\n", integrationResult.result);
  std::printf("exact result    = % .18f\n", expected);
  std::printf("estimated error = % .18f\n", integrationResult.error);
  std::printf("actual error    = % .18f\n",
              integrationResult.result - expected);
  std::printf("intervals       = %zu\n",
              integrationResult.n_intervals);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

On my computer I get:

```
result          = -4.000000000000085265
exact result    = -4.000000000000000000
estimated error =  0.000000000000135447
actual error    = -0.000000000000085265
intervals       = 8
```

Comment: Thanks, is this **extern** snippet definetly written correctly. Oddly wherever I put it gives a **expected unqualified-id at end of input** to bracket } before it and an error **expected unqualified-id before string constant** for the **extern "C"** line. (without it my brackets are fine)

Comment: The reason is that in your case you must call a method and not a function. I have detailed this in my update. Hope it works as right now I have to go, back in on hour. Good luck!

Comment: Whereabouts am I supposed to declare this wrapper? It doesn't work before/in/after the class.

Comment: Back. You can do a forward declaration of your class, then the wrapper, then the class, see my edit

Comment: Now it doesn't know about inverseE- invalid use of incomplete typle 'class cosmo'. (I tried a pseudo forward declaration of inverseE which didn't work as well).

Comment: @Cal I have posted a complete example, hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes thank you this was really helpful, useful to know about forward declaration and I had to install cblas as well. As a result of your help I moved my function outside of my and pass the class information to the function using the params. I think this is the best solution in this situation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Although correct, this answer is cumbersome. With a simple wrapper - it is possible to integrate member functions, lambdas... - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413206/2472169

Comment: I have a question, how does YourClass is scope resolved? what if my structure was inside a method of a class?

Comment: @fedvasu I am not sure if I understand your question well. However, you can still locally declare the IntegrationResult structure inside your method. In my example I declared it as a YouClass member because I want to return it, hence the type must be defined outside the method.

Comment: @fedvasu I have written another version, which is certainly more convenient. Hope it helps.

Comment: @PicaudVincent hey thanks, where is the new version? I meant  "class YourClass" it is not defined in any particular namespace. params is being casted onto the type of "YourClass", what if I declare "YourClass" as a struct or class inside another class which is in turn is in a namespace. I have to do this so as to capture some variables in that namespace and class, it is a pain to instantiate my parent class.

Comment: I see new version is down below, I am having look.

Answer (score 2):

Reading some comments I finally post another version which involves less boilerplate code.

It works as follow:

- there is an `extern "C"  gsl_function_cpp_wrapper_helper` function to insure C ABI (application binary interface). This is the function the gsl's subroutines will use.
- there is a C++ class `gsl_function_cpp_wrapper` that wraps the C++ function/class method thanks to a `std::function`. This wrapper is convertible to a `gsl_function_struct` pointer that uses `gsl_function_cpp_wrapper_helper` as C function, the `std::function`  object is transmitted thank to the gsl's `void *params` parameter
- the demonstration code shows **two examples**, one with a **free function**, the other with a **class method**.

The complete working code, to be compiled with

```
g++ -Wpedantic -std=c++11 testGsl.cpp -lgsl -lcblas
```

is as follows:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

namespace details
{
  extern "C" {
  double gsl_function_cpp_wrapper_helper(double z, void *cpp_f)
  {
    const auto p_cpp_f =
        reinterpret_cast<std::function<double(double)> *>(cpp_f);
    return (*p_cpp_f)(z);
  }
  }
}

class gsl_function_cpp_wrapper
{
  using Cpp_F = std::function<double(double)>;

 public:
  operator const gsl_function_struct *() const { return &gsl_f_; };

  gsl_function_cpp_wrapper(Cpp_F &&cpp_f) : cpp_f_(std::move(cpp_f))
  {
    gsl_f_.function = details::gsl_function_cpp_wrapper_helper;
    gsl_f_.params = &cpp_f_;
  }

  gsl_function_cpp_wrapper(double(f)(double))
      : gsl_function_cpp_wrapper(Cpp_F(f))
  {
  }

  template <typename OBJ>
  gsl_function_cpp_wrapper(double (OBJ::*method)(double) const, const OBJ *obj)
      : gsl_function_cpp_wrapper(
            Cpp_F(std::bind(method, obj, std::placeholders::_1)))
  {
  }
  template <typename OBJ>
  gsl_function_cpp_wrapper(double (OBJ::*method)(double), OBJ *obj)
      : gsl_function_cpp_wrapper(
            Cpp_F(std::bind(method, obj, std::placeholders::_1)))
  {
  }

 protected:
  Cpp_F cpp_f_;
  gsl_function_struct gsl_f_;
};

//----------------

class Class_Example
{
 public:
  double f(double x) const { return std::log(alpha_ * x) / std::sqrt(x); }

 protected:
  double alpha_ = 1;
};

double free_function_example(double x)
{
  const double alpha = 1;
  return std::log(alpha * x) / std::sqrt(x);
}

//----------------

int main()
{
  double result, error;
  gsl_integration_workspace *const w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(1000);
  assert(w != nullptr);

  //----------------

  Class_Example class_example;

  gsl_function_cpp_wrapper wrapper_1(&Class_Example::f, &class_example);

  gsl_integration_qags(wrapper_1, 0, 1, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error);

  std::printf("result          = % .18f\n", result);
  std::printf("estimated error = % .18f\n", error);

  //----------------

  gsl_function_cpp_wrapper wrapper_2(free_function_example);

  gsl_integration_qags(wrapper_2, 0, 1, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error);

  std::printf("result          = % .18f\n", result);
  std::printf("estimated error = % .18f\n", error);

  //----------------

  gsl_integration_workspace_free(w);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```